# Outbound Mail & LDAP integration in Tridion 2009

Tags: 2009, outbound-email, ldap

I'm trying the LDAP integration in an old Tridion 2009 Installation.

I've followed the steps for the integration:

- Add impersonation user to tridion Snapin (following manual)
- Configure this impersonator user in the App pool of Content Manager
  web.
- Configure ISAPI Filter and directory services.

Everithing works ok (log with Ldap users, etc) but there is a problem with Outbound mail.
When I open a Distribution list there appears an error of kind "acces denied" and the error shows the name of the impersonated tridion user (domain\at_desaweb9):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<tcm:Error xmlns:tcm="http://www.tridion.com/ContentManager/5.0" ErrorCode="80040302" Category="16" Source="Kernel" Severity="2"><tcm:Line ErrorCode="80040302" Cause="false" MessageID="4394"><![CDATA[No ha sido posible Inicializar el objeto TDSE.]]><tcm:Token>RESID_4537</tcm:Token><tcm:Token>TDSE</tcm:Token></tcm:Line><tcm:Line ErrorCode="80040302" Cause="true" MessageID="16226"><![CDATA[El acceso ha sido denegado al usuario domain\at_desaweb9.]]><tcm:Token>domain\at_desaweb9</tcm:Token></tcm:Line><tcm:Details><tcm:CallStack><tcm:Location>SystemBLST.GetUserContext</tcm:Location><tcm:Location>SystemBLST.IBLSecurityST_GetUserContext</tcm:Location><tcm:Location>TDSE.Initialize</tcm:Location><tcm:Location>XMLResponder.Initialize</tcm:Location></tcm:CallStack></tcm:Details></tcm:Error>
```

[image]

When I change the user in the Content Manager App Pool setting "NetworkService" despite the new "Ipersonation user" configured for LDAP, then it works fine.

Which kind of authentication must be configured in the Outbound Mail virtual directory for the LDAP integration?

Thanks!